# Create a view that has all child documents inside parent in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have my database setup like this -

Collection: sample -

```
[
    { "parent_id": 1, "children": [2,3], "colour": "yellow" },
    { "parent_id": 2, "children": [],    "colour": "blue" },
    { "parent_id": 3, "children": [],    "colour": "green" },
    { "parent_id": 4, "children": [5],   "colour": "orange" },
    { "parent_id": 5, "children": [], "colour": "red" },
    { "parent_id": 6, "children": [7,8], "colour": "white" },
    { "parent_id": 7, "children": [], "colour": "violet" },
    { "parent_id": 8, "children": [], "colour": "black" }
]
```

I want to create a view in mongoDB such that I get the result like this -

```
[
    { "parent_id": 1, "children": [{ "parent_id": 2, "children": [],    "colour": "blue" },{ "parent_id": 3, "children": [],    "colour": "green" }], "colour": "yellow" },
    { "parent_id": 2, "children": [],    "colour": "blue" },
    { "parent_id": 3, "children": [],    "colour": "green" },
    { "parent_id": 4, "children": [{ "parent_id": 5, "children": [], "colour": "red" },],   "colour": "orange" },
    { "parent_id": 5, "children": [], "colour": "red" },
    { "parent_id": 6, "children": [{ "parent_id": 7, "children": [], "colour": "violet" },{ "parent_id": 8, "children": [], "colour": "black" }], "colour": "white" },
    { "parent_id": 7, "children": [], "colour": "violet" },
    { "parent_id": 8, "children": [], "colour": "black" }
]
```

Basically it can be seen that the children should get substituted in place of the child ids inside the parent, its kind of a self join, but I don't how to join using an array of child ids.

I have tried this thing which is giving me answer very close to what I want -

```
db.sample.find().forEach(function (object) {
    childs=[]
    object.children.forEach(child => {
        childs.push(db.sample.findOne( { "parent_id": child })); 
    });
    object.children_new = childs
    db.test.insert(object)
});
```

This is giving me correct result but the problem is it uses a foreach which is very expensive if I have thousands of lengthy documents, and I can't keep doing this every time the user queries the database. It won't be required to do this everytime but if I store it like above in another collection then it takes more space. The answer to this I found is views ibut I don't know how to create a view that will give result like I want. Can anybody with good mongo proficiency please help ?

Comment: You want only children & you have only 1 level ?
Can i use aggregate function ?

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar yes anything other than the ugly javascript function style of coding I have done

Comment: You use number format as id ?

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar yes, will it be a problem? I have been using it since a long time.

Comment: No, i am only asking you.

Comment: db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      localField: "children",
      foreignField: "parent_id",
      as: "children"
    }
  }
])  use this query

Answer (score 1):

You can simple use either `$lookup` or `$graphLookup` to do this, here is a quick example using `$graphLookup`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "startWith": "$children",
      "connectFromField": "children",
      "connectToField": "parent_id",
      "as": "children",
      "maxDepth": 1,
      
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5LPosiiywNe)

You can also define a [view](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/) using this exact pipeline.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you are a saviour I have been banging my head over this for 2 days